# Two divs in the same row with text in one div getting clipped based on the width of second div

Tags: html, css

I want to have two divs in a single row with the left div's text getting clipped based on the right div's width(the text in the div is dynamically generated) hence we cannot fix the widths of these divs(the text in the right div must be completely visible whereas the text in the left div can be clipped).This image shows the sample output:   [image: The image attached shows the sample output.]

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UzqLZ/1/

here is the html part of code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="text">This text must be hidden if it is overflowing</div>
    <div class="number">88818888.333346</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: I don't understand something - if the number, which is to the right, has a fixed starting point, why can't you fix the width the text div?

Answer (score 1):

How does this look: http://jsfiddle.net/P6Nbg/

I've given the parent position relative and a background colour of white for the number div so it hides the text below.

```
.parent {
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;   
    overflow: hidden;
}

.number {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white; 
    float:right;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    white-space:no-wrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: i want the background color to be transparent. is there a way to do that without changing it to white

Comment: not easily. You could nest it inside another div and give the parent a background color white?

Comment: Your CSS has a lot of superfluous properties not needed for your solution, please see http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/P6Nbg/1/

Comment: @MarcAudet is it possible to hide the text below the number without changing the background color to white of number?

Comment: @MarcAudet I only changed the CSS that was absolutely necessary to provide a solution. I didn't attempt to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.

You need to add an inner wrapper element around your text as follows:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="inner">This text must be hidden if 
                           it is overflowing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="number">88818888.333346</div>
</div>
```

Now use the following CSS:

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    font-size: 1.00em;
    line-height: 1.50em;
}
.number {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.text {
    display: table-cell;
}
.inner {
    height: 1.50em;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Apply `display: table` to `.parent` and specify the font-size and line-height.

Apply `display: table-cell` to `.number` and `.text`.

The `.inner` block will fill up the rest of the width not taken up by `.number`,
and the text will wrap onto two or more lines.  If you specify the height to be one line, then you can use `overflow: hidden` to hide the extra text.

Using `word-break: break-all` may be a good idea.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QBQVg/

Comment: is it possible without changing the background color of number?